# Why are you giving an error in "=" in my VHDL code

Tags: vhdl

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;

ENTITY f_4fir_cont IS
    PORT (
        rst, clk : IN std_logic;
        ctrl : OUT std_logic
    );
END f_4fir_cont;
ARCHITECTURE bhvrl OF f_4fir_cont IS TYPE state_enum IS (s0, s1);
    SIGNAL state : state_enum := s0;
    SIGNAL nexts : state_enum := s1;

BEGIN
    clkp : PROCESS (clk, rst)
    BEGIN
        IF (rst = "0") THEN
            state <= s0;
        ELSIF (clk'EVENT AND clk = "1" AND
            clk'LAST_VALUE = "0") THEN
            state <= nexts;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS clkp;

    transp : PROCESS (state)

    BEGIN
        CASE state IS
            WHEN s0 => nexts <= s1;
            ctrl <= "0";
            WHEN s1 => nexts <= s0;
            ctrl <= "1";
        END CASE;
    END PROCESS transp;
END bhvrl;
```

I found this code in a book and am giving this error IF (rst = "0") THEN:
*Error (10327): VHDL error at f_4fir_cont.vhd(17): can't determine definition of operator ""="" -- found 0*
I have already researched and found nothing to solve, I am starting in VHDL and I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `rst` and `clk` are `std_logic`, which is an enumerated type. You are comparing them to arrays. Change all of the compares to single characters:

```vhdl
if rst = '0' then
```

etc.

Comment: The type of a string literal or character literal is taken from context (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.3.2 Literals, 12.5 The context of overload resolution). There are no visible declarations of functions implementing the equality operator that match usage. Exactly one is required. There are visibility rules used to narrow the candidates based on inner declarative regions and scope (12.3 Visibility, 12.1 Declarative region, 12.2 Scope of declarations). Here there are no matches with overload function declarations made visible by use clauses.